gRPC for large file uploading
i'm currently upgrading a project datalake with microservices communicate by HTTP/1.1 to gRPC communication. I use Quarkus, Java (Gradle) for this project.
Previously, the connection between services is through quarkus.rest-client. Now i have changed it to quarkus.grpc.clients
With uploading small files (about 4KB to 1-2 MB), gRPC does perform significantly better than original but when comes to much larger files, let just say 20MB, my gRPC performs terrible. I did the chunking but stills perform very bad compare to HTTP through i have set the max message size larger with quarkus.grpc.server.max-inbound-message-size
Here, i have 2 services called dashboard and core, i upload a 20MB text file via curl to service dashboard. Then dashboard and core will communicate to each other using gRPC so that core will write to dfs. It does work but stills, terribly slow with large files.
gRPC client (dashboard service):
        ObjectModel obj = new ObjectModel();
        var objJson = "";
        obj.cid = "null";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*64];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                ByteString byteString = ByteString.copyFrom(bytes, 0, len);
                objJson = coreChunkGrpcClient.uploadCoreChunk(Multi.createFrom().item(UploadCoreChunkRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setBearer("Bearer " + jwt.getRawToken())
                        .setOutput(io.quarkus.example.ObjectFormModelChunk.newBuilder()
                                .setMetadata(output.metadata)
                                .setIs(byteString)
                                .setFileID(obj.cid)
                                .build())
                        .build())).onItem().transform(UploadCoreResponse::getToken).await().indefinitely();
                obj.cid = objJson;
            }

gRPC server (core service)
    @POST
    @Path("/file")
    @Transactional
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(summary = "Create a new binary object")
    @Override
    public StreamObserver<UploadCoreChunkRequest> uploadCoreChunk(StreamObserver<UploadCoreResponse> responseObserver) {
        return new StreamObserver<UploadCoreChunkRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(UploadCoreChunkRequest request) {
                var bearer = request.getBearer();
                var inputs = request.getOutput();
                String cid = inputs.getFileID();

                try {
                    var result = insertFileChunk(bearer, inputs, cid);
                    cid = result.getResp().toString();
                    responseObserver.onNext(UploadCoreResponse.newBuilder().setCode(result.getCode()).setMessage(result.getMsg()).setToken(result.getResp().toString()).build());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("error parsing multipart form data {}", e.getMessage());
                    responseObserver.onNext(UploadCoreResponse.newBuilder().setCode(500).setMessage("Internal Error").build());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                ...
            }
        };
    }


Write to fs:
    public LakeHttpResponse insertFileChunk(
            @HeaderParam("Authorization") String bearer,
            @RequestBody(description = "Multipart form data. metadata: extra json info " +
                    "{name:'original filename', gid: 'object group id', length: 'binary length'). file: binary data to save")
            ObjectFormModelChunk input, String cid) throws IOException {

        LakeObjectMetadata meta;
        ByteString is = input.getIs();

        // check chunk and save to backend
        if (cid == null || cid.isEmpty() || cid.isBlank() || cid.equals("null")) {
            cid = fs.create(meta.getName(), meta.getLength(), is);
            return new LakeHttpResponse(200, "OK", cid);
        }
        else {
            if (!fs.insertChunk(cid, is)) {
                return new LakeHttpResponse(500, "Internal error", null);
            }
        }
        LakeObject object = new LakeObject();
        object.setCid(cid);
        Long now = new Date().getTime();
        object.setCreateTime(now);
        object.setAccessTime(now);
        object.setParentId(0L);
        log.info("POST: object metadata saved cid={}", cid);
        return new LakeHttpResponse(200, "OK", cid);
    }

Expected outcome: reduce the time process.

a) your code is too incomplete, We don't see the imports, we can't just take time to makes something up to help you. b) I don't think I've seen such convoluted way to send a single stream of bytes,  POST body with jdk's built-in urlconnection would be enough, unless you want to be fancy with a form multipart upload. c) where is the gzip compression? you are sending multi MB json text in raw form. Gzip that sucker and get 5:1 bandwidth reduction. d) I don't understand why you make 64kB calls only, nor how this gets stiched back in one file. e) stop using 'var', it makes the code unreadable.

@user2023577 thank you for your reply, this is my first question on stackoverflow so i don't really know how should i raise a question, idk whether should i put everything in... For the part b, yes, i tried to make a fancy way. Part d, i send them with an id to merge them after the part write to fs. Part c and e, yes i haven't and i will try that, thank you very much (quite noob tho :v).
